# What parameters affect glCompressedTexSubImage2D, in difference to glCompressedTexImage2D?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4, ati

I have a problem which only affects ATI-graphic cards on PC, but it seems no other graphics hardware, including *Nvidia/Intel/Android/iOS*.

When I create a 2D texture I allocate using `glTexStorage2D`, and then upload the data using `glCompressedTexSubImage2D`.
This works fine on every *Android/iOS/NVidia/Intel* device I have tested. However, on ATI graphics cards (with updated drivers) I get some sort or stride problem as visible in this image below. However, glCompressedTexImage2D works fine.

[image]

The problem appears only on `GL_COMPRESSED_R11_EAC` textures, and not on `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC` (which are the two formats I use).

Does anyone know what texture parameters which might affect `glCompressedTexSubImage2D`, my guess is that all other devices has defaulted some parameter to another value than ATI.

Comment: Are you really having this problem only with GPUs from ATI (pre 2006) or also with newer AMD cards?

Comment: Even with newer ATI cards like Radeon RX 570 Series